# Page cannot be served HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, iis

I'm new in `IIS`, I have asp web applications, and I must add them to the default web site, and when I run a default website, it's fine, but when I run the applications I receive the error:

```
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension
configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file 
should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

In server roles, I have:

[image]

In server Features I have:
[image]

I have tried to register aspnet components:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> .\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

but I recieve this message:

```
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system. 
Administrators should instead install/uninstall A
SP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the Turn Windows Features On/Off dialog
```

I tried this too:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> .\ServiceModelReg.exe -ia`
and
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> .\ServiceModelReg.exe -ir`
but I received this message:

```
[Error]This tool is not supported on this version of Windows.
Administrators should instead install/uninstall Windows Communication
Foundation features using the 'Turn Windows Features On/Off' dialog....
```

I have windows server 2012 and this
IIS version:
[image]

I can't remove or uninstall IIS, because this is our customer server and they use the default website for their Application and myapplications must run on that website.

What can I do??
I hope somebody please help me.

Best Regards

Comment: is it classic asp or asp.net??

Comment: Thanks  shreesha
It's a asp.net
Grettings

Answer (score 0):

404.3 means there is a `MIME` type restriction, meaning that the IIS server will not handle files with whatever type of files you are trying host. 
The handler has to defined under *Handler Mappings* (should be under your website).


[image]

Click *Add Module Mapping* and add the type of the file extension.


[image]

Comment: If it solved your problem, then mark it as an answer. This will help other readers with the same problem.

Comment: Hi sjokkogutten 
Thanks, but my problem persists. my application has aspx pages, and I read that I should not add module mapping for this kind of files.
best regards